# Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'connectivity'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-apk

[        ]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
       * What went wrong:
       Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'connectivity'.
       
       * Try:
       Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
```

--info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
       * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
       
       BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

Comment: What is your compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede 30

Answer (score 0):

this exception can be solved easily by going to ../app/gradle/wrapper/gradlle-wrapper.properties and changed the current version of gradle

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/[your_current_version_of_gradle].zip

to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

If you set ‘org.gradle.configureondemand=true’ in ‘gradle.properties’，please change to false.
It wil be worked !